# Kivy: Can I freely change the position of text within a button? and add another text in the button?

Tags: python, kivy

`t3.py`

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__version__ = "1.0"

import kivy
import os
kivy.require('1.10.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window 
Window.size = (540, 960)

class StationTest(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StationTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_file("t3.kv")

class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


Test2App().run()
```

`t3.kv`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition(direction='left')
    StationTest:

<StationTest>: 
    name: 'StationTest'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size 
            source: 'image/background.png' #backgroundimage
    header: _header
    ScrollView:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 500
            BoxLayout:
                id: _header
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                pos_hint: {'top': 1.0}
                anchor: _anchor
                canvas:
                    Color:              
                        rgba: 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Label:
                    text: "STATION > STATION"
                    font_size: 40
                BoxLayout
                    id: _anchor
                    size_hint_y: 0.3
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:              
                            rgba: 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text: "TEST1234"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                #size_hint: 1, 0.35
                size: 1,0.35
                spacing: 10
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"y":-0.6}
                padding: 0, -200, 0, 0
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 10
        spacing: 0
        padding: [0,100]
        on_parent:
            for i in range(10): txt = 'abcdef'; self.add_widget(Button(text = txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), background_color=(255,255,255,1),
            pos=self.pos, id=txt, color=(0,0,0,1))) # 0~1.0
```

i want add '123456' text apart from 'abcdef' in one button. i can code `txt = 'abcdef' + '123456'` but this is not i wanted. I would like to add the texts in the button and apply the desired options to each text, but it is not easy.

```
on_parent:
    for i in range(10): txt = 'abcdef'; self.add_widget(Button(text = txt, text_size=(cm(2), cm(2)), background_color=(255,255,255,1),
    pos=self.pos, id=txt, color=(0,0,0,1))) # 0~1.0
```

So I have two questions.

1.Can I put two texts that can move independently in one button?

2.Is it possible to set the position of the text freely within the button?

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution with a button containing 3 texts?

Comment: @ikolim sry for the late reply i was too busy recently... and yes. i still couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Please check my post for solution. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the post. You have solved what I had been thinking for weeks.it is really helps me to learn about Kivy.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, feel free to upvote and/or accept it, as you see fit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can I put two texts that can move independently in one button? *No, you cannot*
2. Is it possible to set the position of the text freely within the button? *No, you cannot*

## Solution

Create custom button with inheritance of *ButtonBehavior* and *BoxLayout*. Inside the *BoxLayout*, there are three *Label* widgets.

### Snippet

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
    valign: 'center'
    halign: 'right'

<CustomButton>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1    # black color text

    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 60
    padding: 5, 5, 5, 5

    background_color: [0.50196, 0.50196, 0.50196, 1] if self.state == 'normal' else [0, 1, 1, 1]

    AnchorLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 1, 1, 1] if root.background_color is None else root.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            CustomLabel:
                text: root.route
                color: root.color
                halign: 'left'

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            CustomLabel:
                text: root.stations
                color: root.color

    AnchorLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 1, 1, 1] if root.background_color is None else root.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'

        CustomLabel:
            text: root.commute
            color: root.color
```

## Example

### main.py

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
__version__ = "1.0"

import os
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (540, 960)

from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


def oopath(ndid, uor):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ndid + '.txt')
    return path

##############################################################################################################


class StationTest(Screen):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(StationTest, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        oo = oopath('TESTTEST', 0)
        self.rpandgv(oo)

    def rpandgv(self, path):
        with open(path) as businfo:
            Businfo = []
            for line in businfo:
                Businfo.append(line.rstrip())

        self.businfolist = Businfo
        self.lenbil = int(len(Businfo))
        self.numberoflist = int(len(Businfo)/3)

    def populate_businfo(self, instance):
        for x in range(0, self.lenbil, 3):
            instance.add_widget(CustomButton(route=self.businfolist[x], stations=self.businfolist[x+1], commute=self.businfolist[x+2]))


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class CustomButton(ButtonBehavior, BoxLayout):
    route = StringProperty('')
    stations = StringProperty('')
    commute = StringProperty('')

    def on_release(self):
        print("\troute={0}, stations={1}, commute={2}".format(self.route, self.stations, self.commute))


presentation = Builder.load_file("test.kv")


class Test2App(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation


Test2App().run()
```

### test.kv

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

ScreenManagement:
    transition: SlideTransition(direction='left')
    StationTest:

<StationTest>:
    name: 'StationTest'
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'image/background.png' #backgroundimage

    header: _header

    ScrollView:
        FloatLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 500
            BoxLayout:
                id: _header
                orientation: 'vertical'
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                pos_hint: {'top': 1.0}
                anchor: _anchor
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: 0.8, 0.6, 0.4, 1.0
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                Label:
                    text: "STATION > STATION"
                    font_size: 40
                BoxLayout
                    id: _anchor
                    size_hint_y: 0.3
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                    Label:
                        text: "TEST1234"

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                #size_hint: 1, 0.35
                size: 1,0.35
                spacing: 10
                pos_hint:{"center_x":0.5,"y":-0.6}
                padding: 0, -200, 0, 0

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 10
        spacing: 0
        padding: [0,100]
        on_parent:
            root.populate_businfo(self)


<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
    valign: 'center'
    halign: 'right'

<CustomButton>:
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1    # black color text

    orientation: 'vertical'
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

    size_hint: 1, None
    height: 60
    padding: 5, 5, 5, 5

    background_color: [0.50196, 0.50196, 0.50196, 1] if self.state == 'normal' else [0, 1, 1, 1]

    AnchorLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 1, 1, 1] if root.background_color is None else root.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'left'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            CustomLabel:
                text: root.route
                color: root.color
                halign: 'left'

        AnchorLayout:
            anchor_x: 'right'
            anchor_y: 'top'
            CustomLabel:
                text: root.stations
                color: root.color

    AnchorLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: [1, 1, 1, 1] if root.background_color is None else root.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'

        CustomLabel:
            text: root.commute
            color: root.color
```

## Output

[image: Img01]
[image: Img02]